# Getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException in ASP.NET Core MVC application when reading a file in both Windows and Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, kestrel

[Edit: I found the issue]

In a .NET Core MVC application, I'm using

```
File.ReadAllText "/home/username/someDir/file.txt"
```

function to read text from a file. But it always throws UnauthorizedAccessException

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   '/home/username/someDir' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Permission denied

I tried same in Windows and Linux, but getting the same exception. I have given the directory read, write, execute permissions to all users on both Windows and Linux.

Why does it throws IOException in .NET Core? It worked fine with .NET Framework ASP.NET application though.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry. I was giving a directory path instead of file path to `File.ReadAllText` function. The application is working fine now.